# Adjust scatter marker size to fit imshow cell size

Tags: python, matplotlib, size, markers, scatter

Suppose I have a data plotted with `imshow`, generating something like:

```
X = 10*np.random.rand(5,3)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(X, cmap=cm.jet, interpolation='nearest')
```

[image]

I would like to plot a scatter over this image, which I know how to do.

However, I would like to have the marker size fitting completely a cell of the data plotted with `imshow`. I.e., in the previous example, the data was 5 x 3. If I plot a **X** marker over the [0, 0] position, I would like it to fulfill the orange cell area.

```
ax.scatter(0,0, marker='x')
```

[image]

I know that the `scatter` has a size parameter, but I don't know how to calculate this size.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT - Trying the code posted by @Hyry in the answer below.

This is my code to plot some points:

```
def plot_singularities(x_dim, y_dim, x_steps, y_steps, min_points,
                                              max_points, scalar_field, file_path):
    """
    Plot the singularities of the rotational free scalar field
    :param x_dim : the x dimension of the scalar field
    :param y_dim : the y dimension of the scalar field
    :param x_steps : the discretization in x of the vector field
    :param y_steps : the discretization in y of the vector field
    :param scalar_field : the scalar_field to be plot
    :param min_points : a set (x, y) of min points of the scalar field
    :param max_points : a set (x, y) of max points of the scalar field
    """
    plt.figure()

    ## Plot the scalar field level curves
    x, y = numpy.mgrid[-x_dim/2:x_dim/2:x_steps*1j, -y_dim/2:y_dim/2:y_steps*1j]

    plt.contour(x, y, scalar_field, colors='white', zorder=1, extent=[-x_dim/2.0, x_dim/2.0, -y_dim/2.0, y_dim/2.0])

    ## Plot the critical points
    x = numpy.linspace(-x_dim/2, x_dim/2, x_steps)
    y = numpy.linspace(-y_dim/2, y_dim/2, y_steps)

    # Draw the min points
    x_indices = numpy.nonzero(min_points)[0]
    y_indices = numpy.nonzero(min_points)[1]
    rgba_colors = numpy.zeros((len(x_indices), 4))
    rgba_colors[:, 1] = 0.5
    rgba_colors[:, 3] = min_points[numpy.nonzero(min_points)]
    scatter = plt.scatter(x[x_indices], y[y_indices], color=rgba_colors, marker='$\\otimes$', s=1, zorder=2)
    scatter.__class__ = DataPathCollection
```

I'm getting a bigger marker (the green one):

[image]

My data is 100 x 100. Shouldn't the marker get smaller?

EDIT 2:

With some tests, I noticed that the problem is related to the `extent` parameter in the `imshow` function:

X = 10*np.random.rand(5,5)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(X, cmap="jet", interpolation='nearest', extent=[-5, 5, -5, 5])
scatter = plt.scatter(0,0, marker='x', s=1)
scatter.__class__ = DataPathCollection
plt.show()
```

[image]

How could I adapted the code to overcome this situation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of `PathCollection` is in screen coordinate system, there is no way to set it in data coordinate system. Here is an exmaple that scale paths in data coordinate system. And you can change the `__class__` of the `PathCollection` object to `DataPathCollection`.

The original path of the cross marker is -0.5 ~ 0.5.

```
from matplotlib.collections import PathCollection
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

class DataPathCollection(PathCollection):
    def draw(self, renderer):
        if self._sizes is not None:
            affine = self.axes.transData.get_affine()
            m = affine.get_matrix()
            m[:, 2] = 0
            m[2, :] = 0
            self._transforms = [affine.scale(x, x) for x in self._sizes]
        return Collection.draw(self, renderer)    

X = 10*np.random.rand(5,3)

fig, ax = pl.subplots()
ax.imshow(X, cmap="jet", interpolation='nearest')
scatter = ax.scatter(0,0, marker='x', s=1)
scatter.__class__ = DataPathCollection
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Hi, @Hyry. I tried to apply your suggestion in my code but I got a bigger marker (I was expecting it to be smaller). Would you mind to read my EDIT? Thank you.

Comment: @pceccon, `s=1` means the width and height of the marker is 1 in the data coordinate system. From your plot, it seems that the size of the green one is 1.

Comment: To be 1 means that I could have 100 markers side by side whiteout overlap? Cause I don't think that is possible, and this is what I was trying to achieve. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, @Hyry. By simple adding the extent parameter in the imshow function, I could observed that the problem is related to it. However, didn't solve it yet.